# Как получить имя раскладки клавиатуры

Tags: c#

Кусочек кода:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern ushort GetKeyboardLayout([In] int idThread);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId([In] IntPtr hWnd,[Out, Optional] IntPtr lpdwProcessId);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
public static string mss;

static ushort GetKeyboardLayout()
        {
            return GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero));
        }
```

Теперь когда я пытаюсь получить раскладку клавиатуры

```
ushort lang = GetKeyboardLayout();
mss = lang.ToString();
TextBox1.Text = "Первоначальная раскладка: " + mss + "\n";
```

Он показывает не `Rus` или `Eng` а цифрами типо `1049` и.т.д

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System.Globalization;
```

```
int id = GetKeyboardLayout();
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(id);
this.Text = id + " " + ci.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName + " " + ci.Name;
```

И [там](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) ещё много интересного есть.

---

Обратите внимание, что у вас неправильная сигнатура P/Invoke! Функция [`GetKeyboardLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646296.aspx) возвращает хэндл, поэтому [правильная сигнатура](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetKeyboardLayout.html) такая:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(int idThread);
```

Согласно документации,

> The low word contains a Language Identifier for the input language and the high word contains a device handle to the physical layout of the keyboard.

Поэтому нам нужно извлечь младшее слово:

```
static ushort GetKeyboardLayout()
{
    return (ushort)GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(),
                                                              IntPtr.Zero));
}
```

Comment: +1, но P/Invoke-сигнатура для GetKeyboardLayout у ТС неправильная => стоит ждать крешей. Там в реальности IntPtr.

Comment: И у меня падает GetCultureInfo, если не обрезать аргументу старшие биты (`id & 0xffff`).

Comment: @VladD, а как ты из `ushort` смог получить что-то со старшими битами? о_О

Comment: @VladD, хм.. да, там как бы хэндл. Но падать ведь нечему - это ж регистр просто.

Comment: Ну, у меня выходит id = 0xfffffffff0c10419, например. С таким значением падает.

Comment: «The low word contains a Language Identifier for the input language and the high word contains a device handle to the physical layout of the keyboard.» (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646296.aspx)

Comment: @VladD, я имел в виду, что `ushort` уже сам сделал `id & 0xffff`, а при расширении до int'а там появиться нечему, т. к. он unsigned был. Про физическую раскладку интересно. А ещё 4 байта - всё равно же мусор?

Comment: Чёта я очень неуверен, что можно соврать в сигнатуре P/Invoke и надеяться, что будет правильный каст. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040119-00/?p=41003/

Comment: Ну, наверное верхние байты — просто знаковое расширение.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52826/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-vladd).