# Как проверить раскладку клавиатуры на нужный язык?

Tags: c#

Первое что делаю это собираю информацию о языках в системе:

```
public static InputLanguage GetLanguage(string language)
{
  language = language.ToLower();
  foreach (InputLanguage lang in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages)
  {
    if (lang.LayoutName.ToLower() == language)
    {
        return lang;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Затем пробую проверить язык тот или не тот через функцию `if`

```
if(InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage == GetLanguage("us"))
{
  Console.Write("Определён Английский!");
}
else if (InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage == GetLanguage("ru"))
{
  Console.Write("Определён Русский!");
}
```

Но он не определяет его.
Может Я не так его определяю?

Как решить задачу?

Comment: Я вставил в цикл форыч строку `Console.WriteLine(lang.LayoutName);` - в моей системе выводит языки `US` и `Russian`. Таким образом, `ru` не подходит.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Я пробовал `US` и `Russian` - А так же для Русской винды `США`, и "Русская", не определяется.

Comment: Вы сравниваете _ссылки_. Естественно, они не равны. Возвращайте `LayoutName` и его сравнивайте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использованный вами способ не будет правильно работать в консольном приложении, только в приложении WinForms.

В консоли на данный момент мне удалось однозначно получить только язык ввода по-умолчанию и системную локаль. С текущей раскладкой пока не далось справиться даже через WinAPI (подсмотрено [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621911/198316)), возвращает только язык ввода по-умолчанию. Если найдется решение, допишу сюда же.

Ошибки в текущем решении и способы их устранения ниже:

1. Вы некорректно сравниваете названия языков. Если хотите использовать двух-буквенные обозначения, то исправьте условие в `GetLanguage` на такое

   ```
   ...
   if (lang.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == language)
   ...
   ```

   В таком случае английский будет обозначен как `en`, а не `us`, независимо от конкретной его вариации.

   Если нужно учитывать вариант языка, то замените условие на такое:

   ```
   ...
   if (lang.Culture.Name == language)
   ...
   ```

   и используйте стандартные обозначения языков: `en-US`, `ru-RU`
2. При сравнении объектов `InputLanguage` нельзя использовать оператор `==`, так как он будет сравнивать только ссылки на объекты `InputLanguage`. Вместо этого используйте метод `Equals`, который в данном классе [переопределен](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) и возвращает корректный ответ при эквивалентности языков.

   ```
   ...
   if (InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Equals(GetLanguage("ru")))
   ...
   ```

---

Список всех языков, которые знает ваша система, их названия и атрибуты можно получить так

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
```

Comment: А замену нужно изменить в внутри метода `GetLanguage`?

Comment: @Дмитрий пункт 2 выполняется внутри метода GetLanguage. Пункт 3 выполняется в там, где вы сравниваете текущий и заданный языки. Но это не будет работать в консольном приложении. Решения для консоли я еще не нашел. Если нужна именно консоль, то добавьте соответствующую метку к вопросу, может еще кто подтянется

Answer (score 2):

Используйте свойство `Culture` для `InputLanguage`, чтобы узнать, на каком языке основан макет клавиатуры.

```
string iso6391TwoLetterCode = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

switch(iso6391TwoLetterCode)
{
    case "ru":
        Console.WriteLine("Russian is defined!");
        break;
    case "en":
        Console.WriteLine("English is defined!");
        break;
    case "de":
        Console.WriteLine("German is defined!");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Some other language is defined!");
        break;
}
```